# Extra Adventures for Castle Ravenloft

Tags: variants, castle-ravenloft, dnd-adventure-system

Where can I find other adventures for Castle Ravenloft? So far I've only found [the two bonus adventures](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/duad/20100816) that WotC released.

Answer (score 5):

**BoardGameGeek [Castle RavenLoft](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/59946/dungeons-dragons-castle-ravenloft-board-game)** has quite a few used-made scenarios and extra characters.

The most are listed in the [**Variants**](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/forum/553200/dungeons-dragons-castle-ravenloft-board-game/variants) forum, although you may look around in there a bit and find some others under "rules" maybe.

One of my favorites is "[Crypts And Creepers](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/564387/crypts-and-creepers-unofficial-expansion)", although it's more of an *'expansion'*, not just another scenario.

[WotC](http://www.wizards.com/) is also having a "[**Build your own scenario**](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/promotions.aspx)" competition, so you should see more available on-line when that happens also.

Here's a link I just found that has most of the user-created adventures listed and ranked:

[BGG Castle RavenLoft Adventure Database](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/59113/item/1424794#item1424794)

Comment: I don't see the individual adventures, just the list that ranks them.

Comment: The first post is the current rankings, the links to the adventures are posted below that.

Answer (score 0):

Update: link for "official" 2 bonus adventures is [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20151111035622/http://archive.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/duad/20100816)